# Is it possible to record and stream audio from a raspberry pi to a PC?

Tags: hardware, audio, ethernet

I'm trying to come up with a project and I want to know how feasible the following is:

I want to be able to stream audio from a raspberry pi to a PC. This includes:

1. Connecting a mic to the pi
2. Streaming audio to PC over ethernet / wifi.

How feasible is this?

Is there anything I should look into before I start?

Comment: just before you start, the PI does NOT provide mic interface. You will need a USB sound card (>2€) or a USB webcam with a built in mic.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked for sometime over the internet for such a solution and it seems quite doable (although I finally didn't try this myself).
You should have a look at the libraries DarkIce (recording) and IceCast2 (streaming).

Most tutorials about streaming audio use these two. For example :

http://www.t3node.com/blog/live-streaming-mp3-audio-with-darkice-and-icecast2-on-raspberry-pi/

Good luck ! And tell us how it goes !

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy and a one liner bash command:

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat | ssh -C user@remoteip aplay -f dat
```

Full explanation [here](https://blog.mutsuda.com/raspberry-pi-into-an-audio-spying-device-7a56e7a9090e)