# How can I record audio from my RPI and save it to my PC (server)?

Tags: raspbian, usb, audio

I would like to [record audio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/how-can-i-record-audio-using-a-microphone) from a usb device connected to my RPI and save it to a server (my pc on the same network).

OS: RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy

Model: B

USB Mic:  Sound-Tech 1000

Once the USB mic is connected, it does show up as:
[image]

I have reviewed [this helpful link on recording sound,](http://www.g7smy.co.uk/?p=283) but that uses a USB soundcard instead.

As my RPI has limited memory, I need to record a 4+ hour long session and would like it saved on my PC.

How can I set up my RPI to do this? Can I connect it to a service on my desktop and have it stream the audio the RPI captures?

Comment: Sorry, This is a dup: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13442/is-it-possible-to-record-and-stream-audio-from-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-pc?rq=1  .... just saw this now

Comment: If you simply want to store the recording on an external PC, another possibility would be to mount a remote folder locally on the Pi and store the recording within that folder.