# View Twitch stream on rPi, but with sending the stream audio to Windows?

Tags: networking, audio, windows, alsa, streaming

What:
I want to display a Twitch video stream locally (on the rPi, over HDMI) but send the audio to a desktop on the same network.

Why:
To free up video resources for other things (gaming, bitcoin mining).

Why not use the hardware headphone jack:
Ridiculous amounts of noise produced by the pi's headphone jack proximity to the switched-mode power supply.

Why not use audio over HDMI:
My monitor has no audio output, and I have no adapters to break it out (never seen the need, although this case is one).

Why not use USB audio:
USB Audio support for the Pi generally has a history of being shoddy. I would be open to this option if I could find (or be told of) a good guide to setting it up.

How:
So I've been fiddling about with various solutions to this problem, but everything I've read about or tried turns out to be limited to performing the reverse purpose (sending audio from a PC to an SBC), or is restricted to Apple devices (AirPlay).

So far I've looked at SqueezeBox on OSMC and Signalyst on DietPi... Both aren't really designed for this use case. So far I prefer DietPi as far as an OS goes, but I'm open to trying anything.

Possible solutions that don't apply to me:

- PulseAudio seems like it has a decent solution for networked audio but PulseAudio isn't supported on Windows, meaning I'd have to run a VM just to receive audio which kind of defeats the purpose of freeing up resources.
- [This](https://blog.mutsuda.com/raspberry-pi-into-an-audio-spying-device-7a56e7a9090e) example from [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75469) suggesting streaming audio over SSH. If Windows had a good SSH server this would be viable.

Thank you for any input you can provide!

Comment: What is the actual question here? Could you try to reduce it to minimal information that still describes your *specific* problem?  As it is now there seems to be a lot of unnecessary information and yet not enough detail on what you've done.

Comment: Have you tried a simple (and inexpensive) in-line HDMI audio extractor?
They are less than $15 on places like Amazon. Try googling "Wiistar Extractor Optical Splitter Converter" to see what I mean.

Comment: @MrChips I have, but couldn't find any that do HDMI-HDMI. I already have an HDMI splitter though so the destination video type doesn't matter. This might be the easiest route... thanks for the lingo.

Comment: @Brick So you want me to intentionally be vague so you don't have to read as much? I went into detail so that I wouldn't have people responding suggesting things I've already tried or that won't work for this problem.

Comment: I want you to be concise so that we can figure out where your problem is.

Comment: The question is (see the title) "What can I use to view a Twitch stream on rPi, but send the stream audio to Windows, be it software or hardware?"

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr just do it in hardware with a splitter or an extractor. Thanks [Brick](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/55740/brick) for your attempt at reading.